# SQL : a GROUP BY issue in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, select, group-by

Here is the database table

```
╔════╦═════════════╦══════════════════╦═══════╗
║ id ║ customer_id ║    last_seen     ║ param ║
╠════╬═════════════╬══════════════════╬═══════╣
║  1 ║       12345 ║ 2012-08-01 12:00 ║     1 ║
║  2 ║       22345 ║ 2012-08-01 12:00 ║     1 ║
║  3 ║       32345 ║ 2012-08-01 12:00 ║     1 ║
║  4 ║       42345 ║ 2012-08-01 12:00 ║     1 ║
║  5 ║       52345 ║ 2012-08-01 12:00 ║     1 ║
║  6 ║       12345 ║ 2012-09-01 12:00 ║     2 ║
║  7 ║       12345 ║ 2012-10-01 12:00 ║     3 ║
╚════╩═════════════╩══════════════════╩═══════╝
```

where `id` is an AUTO INCREMENT primary key.

What I want to achieve is to get the last record of each `customer_id`. Expected Result :

```
╔════╦═════════════╦══════════════════╦═══════╗
║ id ║ customer_id ║    last_seen     ║ param ║
╠════╬═════════════╬══════════════════╬═══════╣
║  2 ║       22345 ║ 2012-08-01 12:00 ║     1 ║
║  3 ║       32345 ║ 2012-08-01 12:00 ║     1 ║
║  4 ║       42345 ║ 2012-08-01 12:00 ║     1 ║
║  5 ║       52345 ║ 2012-08-01 12:00 ║     1 ║
║  7 ║       12345 ║ 2012-10-01 12:00 ║     3 ║
╚════╩═════════════╩══════════════════╩═══════╝
```

I tried this SQL, but it returns incorrect result :

```
SELECT customer_id, param, last_seen 
FROM `my_table` 
GROUP BY customer_id 
ORDER BY last_seen DESC
```

What am I missing here ?

**UPDATE**: Table structure ( output of `DESC my_table` )

```
+--------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field        | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+--------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id           | int(11)      | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| customer_id  | varchar(8)   | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| last_seen    | datetime     | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| param        | int(11)      | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
+--------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

Comment: In ANSI SQL you cannot select ugrouped field in `group by` query  because it value is undefined. Somewhat MySQL allows it.

Comment: can you please check if the the `last_seen` value of record id `6` is correct?

Comment: @KuyaJohn it's a typo, now corrected

Comment: waw which a design edit :) , thx @saharsh shah

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The idea behind the subquery is that it separately gets the latest `last_seen` value for each `Customer_ID`. The result of the subquery is then joined with the original table provided that the condition must be met: the `CustomerID` and the *dates* must match with each other.

```
SELECT  a.*
FROM    Customer a
        INNER JOIN
        (
            SELECT Customer_ID, MAX(last_seen) maxDate
            FROM Customer
            GROUP BY Customer_ID
        ) b ON a.Customer_ID = b.Customer_ID AND
                a.last_seen = b.maxDate
ORDER BY a.ID
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/43acb/1)

*Follow-up Question: can you please check if the the `last_seen` value of record id `6` is correct?*

Comment: Typo, now fixed for record id 6. my MySQL server hangs when executing this query & stops responding.

Comment: how many records do you have? do you also have an index `Customer_ID`?

Comment: I have index on `id` column, but now `Customer_ID` column. I have ~220,000 records

Comment: the reason why your server *hangs* (but actually not) is because it is prforming `FULL TABLE SCAN`

Comment: can you post here the result of the query `DESC yourTableName;`?

Comment: updated the schema. Yes, this could be the reason. I should add an index to the `customer_id`

Comment: Okay, the SQL is finally executed, in 25 seconds after adding the INDEX. Before adding the Index, the SQL runs forever.

Comment: You should add an index on `(customer_ID, last_seen)` for even better performance.

Comment: @ShivanRaptor: Just curious. Could you run a query from my answer on your dataset. What time does it take?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a [SQLFiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/7c4ee/4)

In MySQL you can do it in this way:

```
select ID,CUSTOMER_ID,LAST_SEEN,PARAM from
(
   select t.*,
       if(@i=customer_id,0,1) isLast,
       @i:=customer_id 
       from `my_table` t,(select @i:=0) t1 
   order by customer_id,last_seen desc
) t2 where isLAst=1
```

Comment: while referring to my DB schema, what is `t` , `t1` and `t2` ? I can't run the query.

Comment: I've changed query according using `my_table`. t,t1,t2 are aliases

Comment: finally managed to run your query. However, PHP memory exhausted & phpmyadmin stop responding. using MySQL 5.1